# How to handle special characters in API URL - Retrofit

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2, special-characters

I'm using Kotlin and retrofit in my Android App to call API's, but some of the API URLs have these characters in them: `^, #, ~.`

I'm using the `GET` API method. My host URL does not have special / strange characters in them nor does my API method names, but the API methods that I've set up; have a few parameters; and sometimes the arguments I'm sending, when calling the API methods, have these special characters in them.

In those cases I'm not getting a response back and the API call fails.

I've noticed that retrofit changes my URL. It replaces any special character with 3 other characters. I've tested my URLs directly in a browser and in Postman, and they work fine.

Is there something specific I have to do in Kotlin to make retrofit be OK with my special characters?

Comment: The "replacing" retrofit does is on purpose. This is called url encoding. Your browser and postman also do this under the hood

Comment: Why do I then still get 400: Bad Request. Is retrofit encoding it differently than my browser / Postman?

Comment: I don't know, check your server logs

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns. Can I manually encode my URL in Kotlin before I send it to retrofit?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
import java.net.URLEncoder

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val url = "http://foo bar/"
    println(URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8")) // note: encodes space to + not %20
}
```

Output:

```
http%3A%2F%2Ffoo+bar%2F
```

**You should avoid Special character in Api**

URL encoding is often required to convert special characters (such as "/", "&", "#", ...), because special characters:

```
 1. Have special meaning in some contexts, or
 2. Are not a valid character for an URL, or
 3. could be altered during the transfer.
```

For instance, the "#" character needs to be encoded because it has a special meaning of that of an HTML anchor.

The  character needs to be encoded because it is not a valid URL character. Also, some characters, such as "~" might not transport properly across the internet. Instead of proceeding with the complex process you should focus on correcting the old one.

More you can read [here](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/251/0/using-url-encoding-to-handle-special-characters-in-a-document-uri).

Comment: How can I encode my URL in Kotlin before I send it to retrofit?

Comment: If the API contains special characters and you will encode it you will not receive the response. So instead you should try changing the API structure as mention above.

Comment: If my API will result in no response or 400: Bad Request; what is the purpose of encoding a URL in the first place?

Comment: Changin the API means - Change the server-side API URL. Not anything in-app.

Comment: I understand changing the API URL on the server; and removing any of those special characters in the URL there will work. I'm just not understanding why encoding a URL is useful if you can't get a response after encoding a URL. What is the purpose of encoding a URL?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I appreciate.